# How to allow postgres to connect to Django using torify

Tags: django, postgresql, tor

I'm trying to run a Django server using torify, but when I run `torify python3 manage.py runserver` I get below error:

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I've already added this code to the torrc:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/

HiddenServicePort 5432 127.0.0.1:5432

HiddenServicePort 5432 localhost:5432
```

or even just this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/

HiddenServicePort 5432 127.0.0.1:5432
```

But both of them didn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? What error message are you receiving?

Comment: We need to see the actual code and the actual error message to help.